# R Studio Sys.which("openMalaria") returns ""

Tags: r

I am trying to use the [openMalaria utilities](https://github.com/SwissTPH/r-openMalariaUtilities/blob/HEAD/R/simulation.R) R package. This package creates XML files which are then fed into the openMalaria program through R.

I keep getting error message "openMalaria not found". I checked the source code and it seems that

```
Sys.which("openMalaria")
openMalaria 
         ""
```

so the runSimulations function won't call the program to actually run the simulation.

How can I call the executable file? Using macOS Monterey, RStudio  version 4.2.2 and openMalaria version 44.

I have already tried adding the filepath to the PATH variable with the following code.

```
> path <- Sys.getenv("PATH")
> path <- c("/Users/MYNAME/OM/openMalaria", path)
> path <- paste0(path, collapse = ":")
> Sys.setenv(PATH=path)
> Sys.getenv("PATH")
```

Doing so seems successful, as

```
Sys.getenv("PATH")
```

now shows

```
"/Users/MYNAME/OM/openMalaria:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Users/MYNAME/Applications/quarto/bin:/usr/texbin:/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/quarto/bin:/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS"
```

but I still get

```
Sys.which("openMalaria")
openMalaria 
         ""
```

Do I have the wrong filepath? I'm not sure how to figure out how to point to the executable file for openMalaria. Sqlite3, which is a dependency of openMalaria, seems to work ok:

```
> Sys.which("sqlite3")
           
sqlite3 
"/usr/bin/sqlite3"
```

Comment: Is `/Users/MYNAME/OM/openMalaria` a directory or a file? Your PATH values should all be directories. If `openMalaria` is a file, then set your path to include just `/Users/MYNAME/OM/`

Comment: If you want to be quick/hasty, use `Sys.setenv(PATH = paste0("/Users/MYNAME/OM/:", Sys.getenv("PATH")))`. If you want to be a little more robust, you could `Sys.setenv(PATH=paste(unique(c("/Users/MYNAME/OM/", strsplit(Sys.getenv("PATH"), ":")[[1]]))), collapse=":"))`, where calling it repeatedly does not produce duplicate entries.

Comment: @MrFlick this solved my problem. Thank you SO much. I didn't realize you couldn't point to the file itself.

Comment: Someone (possibly the OP) should post an answer, or delete the question if you don't think the answer will be useful to future readers ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be helpful to keep this up as there are very few sources for openMalaria problems outside the wiki.

@MrFlick gets the credit for this answer, but yes, the PATH should point to the directory the file sits in, not the file itself.

Then `Sys.which("openMalaria")` is successful!

Another note, which should be common practice but I also forgot - don't use any spaces in folder or file names.